# Updated default SSIS parameter value not being used

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I'm having trouble updating a default SSIS package parameter value, and if someone could explain where I am going wrong or why it won't work that would be much appreciated.

For a bit of background, I have a packages that I deploy using Azure yaml pipelines. For different environments I want different default values for the parameters. So my DEV environment would be my local one where I can change the parameter value within Visual Studio to whatever I require. Before committing and deploying to UAT I change the parameter value to that for UAT. Then as the package progresses to the PROD environment it still has the UAT parameter value. So after a successful deployment I run a script to update parameter default value to be that required by PROD.

An example might help illustrate. One package copies all files in a certain location via a script task before going on to do other things with the copied files. The location of the files is passed into the script task as ReadOnlyVariables. Locally that can be wherever. On UAT they are held in a specific mapped network location, say T:\Databases, so that becomes the parameter value, the package is deployed through the pipeline and everything works as expected on UAT. However, on PROD the files are held in a different mapped network location, say F:\Databases. I want that to be the default parameter value for PROD.

I'm updating the parameter by running the below SQL:

```sql
UPDATE ssisdb.[catalog].object_parameters
SET    design_default_value = REPLACE(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), design_default_value), 'T:', 'F:')
WHERE  [object_name] = myPackage.dtsx
       AND SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(design_default_value, 'BaseType') = N'nvarchar'
       AND CONVERT(NVARCHAR(4000), design_default_value) LIKE 'T:'
```

When I check the parameter default values, by querying `ssisdb.[catalog].object_parameters` or via configuring the package, it reports that the value is 'F:' and so has been updated as expected:

[image]

But, when I run the package it looks for files in 'T:' which is not what I would expect.

Can the default parameter values be updated in this way? Or am I doing it wrong?

And yes, I can just override the parameter and it works as expected but, I'm curious why changing the default parameter value doesn't work.

**Update 1**
This package does use environment variables and, yes I could include this path as one but typically it's only the drive that changes.

To have just the drive as a variable is a bit annoying - the package would need minor edits to make the full path from the environment variable drive and the parameter, that in turn would have become a path without a drive letter which I don't think is natural.

Putting the entire path in would be another option but I'm using a common set of environment variables i.e. a SSIS folder with just the variables, and all SSIS packages (50+) will use those. So in my plan only the common variables would be added e.g. database name not package specific ones. Even if I had package specific environment variables when running the package I can only reference one environment.

Comment: How are you running the package? Eg, by right clicking on the package in the SSIS catalog and going through the "execute" dialog? By starting a SQL agent job? Via the `start_execution` stored procedure in the catalog DB? Does your organisation typically use SSIS catalog environments? (You should do this by the way, rather than scripting environment specific changes into the `object_parameters`).

Comment: @allmhuran Ordinarily the packages are run via jobs. But, for this issue it doesn't matter how you run it, job, "execute" dialog or SP the result is the same... it uses the original default parameter value.

On environment variables please see my edit (it was making the comment too long)